# How to use cumulative_sum with a previous aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to plot a cumulative sum of some events, per day. The [cumulative sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-sum-aggregation.html) seems to be the way to go so I tried to reuse the example given in the docs.

The first aggregation works fine, the following query

```
{
   "aggs": {
       "vulns_day" : {
           "date_histogram" :{
               "field": "HOST_START_iso",
               "interval": "day"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

gives replies such as

```
        (...)
        {
           "key_as_string": "2016-09-08T00:00:00.000Z",
           "key": 1473292800000,
           "doc_count": 76330
        },
        {
           "key_as_string": "2016-09-09T00:00:00.000Z",
           "key": 1473379200000,
           "doc_count": 37712
        },
        (...)
```

I then wanted to query the cumulative sum of `doc_count` above via

```
{
   "aggs": {
       "vulns_day" : {
           "date_histogram" :{
               "field": "HOST_START_iso",
               "interval": "day"
           }
       },
       "aggs": {
           "vulns_cumulated": {
               "cumulative_sum": {
                   "buckets_path": "doc_count"
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

but it gives an error:

```
"reason": {
               "type": "search_parse_exception",
               "reason": "Could not find aggregator type [vulns_cumulated] in [aggs]",
```

I see that  [`bucket_path`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#buckets-path-syntax) should point to the elements to be summed and the example for cumulative aggregations created a specific intermediate sum but I do not have anything to sum (beside `doc_count`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Since `doc_count` did not seem to be available, I tried to retrieve `stats` for the time parameter, and use its `count` value. It worked:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "vulns_day": {
         "date_histogram": {
            "field": "HOST_START_iso",
            "interval": "day"
         },
        "aggs": {
          "dates_stats": {
              "stats": {
                  "field": "HOST_START_iso"
              }
          },
         "vulns_cumulated": {
            "cumulative_sum": {
               "buckets_path": "dates_stats.count"
            }
         }
      }
   }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should change your query like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "vulns_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "HOST_START_iso",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "document_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "HOST_START_iso"
          }
        },
        "vulns_cumulated": {
          "cumulative_sum": {
            "buckets_path": "document_count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but neither works. The first one (where the second `aggs` is at the same level as `date_histogram`) returns `No aggregation found for path [doc_count]` and the second one `cumulative sum aggregation [vulns_cumulated] must have a histogram or date_histogram as parent`

Comment: I update my query. I dont know it can work but I try to create according to given information. You can also check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-sum-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-pipeline-cumulative-sum-aggregation this page. I think, you can use value_count aggregation to get doc_count value. But I could not example on my local machine. I only try to examine.